# Retrieving a row identity

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want to return the row ID from SQL Server through C#. Below is the code I am using:

```
const string sqlQuery = "SELECT ID " +
                        "FROM CleaningCycleTime " +
                        "WHERE ActualFinishDayTime < DATEADD(day, -60, GETDATE()) AND LotWorkOrder = @LotWorkOrder AND Process = @Process AND CleanType = @CleanType " +
                        "Group By ID " +
                        "Having (Min(ActualStartDayTime) IS NOT NULL AND Max(ActualFinishDayTime) IS NOT NULL)";

using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, _myConnection))
{
    try
    {
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LotWorkOrder", lstOpenCleans.SelectedItem.ToString());
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Process", lstProcess.SelectedItem.ToString());
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CleanType", lstProcess.SelectedItem.ToString());
        _myConnection.Open();
        SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            txtID.Text = myReader["ID"].ToString();
        }

        _myConnection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ee.ToString());
        _myConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

Which generates

```sql
SELECT ID 
FROM CleaningCycleTime 
WHERE ActualFinishDayTime < DATEADD(day, -60, GETDATE()) 
  AND LotWorkOrder = 'X90744' 
  AND Process = 'PRE BLEND' 
  AND CleanType = 'FULL' 
GROUP BY 
   ID 
HAVING 
   (Min(ActualStartDayTime) IS NOT NULL 
   AND Max(ActualFinishDayTime) IS NOT NULL)
```

When I run the generated query in SQL Server Management Studio, it returns a value. When I do this in C#, it gets as far as `myReader.Read()`, but never loops

Comment: Have you checked the generated code with SQL Profiler to make sure it is emitting what you expect?

Comment: I honestly did not know such a thing existed.  I am looking it up right now

Comment: How do you know it never loops? Does your reader returns data at all? Moreover, your query looks strange to me.

Comment: Before the Read() loop, put in a call to reader.HasRows. Is the value of HasRows true or false before the loop?

Comment: The value of Process (PRE BLEND) has a space. Are you sure that it is being quoted correctly so the space isn't messing up the parser?

Comment: It would be hard to know if this is reading all the rows or not because each iteration through the loop resets the text of your textbox.

Comment: @Rahul I set breakpoints and can see that while loop is hit, but never goes inside

Comment: That means reader has nothing (OR) query won't return any result.

Comment: As it turns out I am an incredibly huge dummy.  For my third parameter I was pulling from the wrong place.  However, there was some great advise in here of stuff I did not know and I will apply it to what I am doing.  And thanks for pointing out that tracer.  I am so sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I notice a couple of things:

**1 -**  No quotes around your C# string where appropriate.

SQL:

```
AND LotWorkOrder = 'X90744' 
AND Process = 'PRE BLEND' 
AND CleanType = 'FULL'
```

vs 
C#:

```
"AND LotWorkOrder = @LotWorkOrder AND Process = @Process AND CleanType = @CleanType "
```

**2 -** We do not see how your connection is defined. Why not wrap it in a using statement?

To be concise:

```
using (var cn = new SqlConnection("connection string"))
{
    cn.Open();
    using (var cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
    {

        // set the command text
const string sqlQuery = "SELECT ID " +
                        "FROM CleaningCycleTime " +
                        "WHERE ActualFinishDayTime < DATEADD(day, -60, GETDATE()) AND LotWorkOrder = '@LotWorkOrder' AND Process = '@Process' AND CleanType = '@CleanType' " +
                        "Group By ID " +
                        "Having (Min(ActualStartDayTime) IS NOT NULL AND Max(ActualFinishDayTime) IS NOT NULL)";
        cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;

        // Add your paramters to the command object.
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LotWorkOrder", lstOpenCleans.SelectedItem.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Process", lstProcess.SelectedItem.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CleanType", lstProcess.SelectedItem.ToString());

        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                txtID.Text = myReader["ID"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

New sqlQuery:

```
const string sqlQuery = "SELECT ID " +
                        "FROM CleaningCycleTime " +
                        "WHERE ActualFinishDayTime < DATEADD(day, -60, GETDATE()) AND LotWorkOrder = '@LotWorkOrder' AND Process = '@Process' AND CleanType = '@CleanType' " +
                        "Group By ID " +
                        "Having (Min(ActualStartDayTime) IS NOT NULL AND Max(ActualFinishDayTime) IS NOT NULL)";
```

Comment: NO. You have turned the parameters into string constants.

Comment: Forgot to add that he should add the parameters to the command object  instead of setting the command text.

Comment: You need to set the text AND add the parameters, both of which were done in the original post.